# Custom Spinner - how to?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a view like this on Facebook application.

[image: facebook example]
but all I've got is this

[image: my design]
My boss says it's ugly. I've tried everything but I don't know which visual element is that, I don't know where Facebook gets their widgets for Android, they look so different or doesn't exist.

I made this way:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutPhone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/enterMobileNumber">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country_code"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:text="@string/select_your_country"
        android:textColor="#9B9B9B"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_sortdown_48px"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/country_code"
            android:background="#737373" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

There's any way I can get the proper design?

Comment: can you fix the links in your question? Would be helpful to see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: try using a spinner instead with a custom theme https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.androhub.com/android-spinner/).

Answer (score 0):

Use spinner

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutPhone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/enterMobileNumber">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/country_code"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:text="@string/select_your_country"
            android:textColor="#9B9B9B"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

            <Spinner
          android:id="@+id/spinner"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

For your referance https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spinner_control.htm